# Regex pattern syntax exception

Tags: java, regex

I am using this `regex expression`:

```
[Ss]([0-9]+)[][ ._-]*[Ee]([0-9]+)([^\\/]*)$
```

It throws an exception when I am converting into a `pattern`:

```
pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp.get(i));


    05-15 11:16:06.914: E/AndroidRuntime(5268): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Missing closing bracket in character class near index 43:
05-15 11:16:06.914: E/AndroidRuntime(5268): [Ss]([0-9]+)[][ ._-]*[Ee]([0-9]+)([^\\/]*)$
05-15 11:16:06.914: E/AndroidRuntime(5268):                                            ^
05-15 11:16:06.914: E/AndroidRuntime(5268):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)
05-15 11:16:06.914: E/AndroidRuntime(5268):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:400)
05-15 11:16:06.914: E/AndroidRuntime(5268):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:383)
05-15 11:16:06.914: E/AndroidRuntime(5268):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:374)
```

It works fine when running on a `java regex tester`. I believe I need to escape some characters here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 issues I see here:

1. You are using an empty character class `[]`
2. Backslash needs more escaping

You can use this regex:

```
[Ss]([0-9]+)[ ._-]*[Ee]([0-9]+)([^\\\\/]*)$
```